# Exit button not working-C#

Tags: c#, button

I am working on creating a file managing program. I have a file button in the top left corner, and the dropdown menu has an exit button. Here is a section of code:

```
    private void  exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I have tried all sorts of different commands for exiting the program, but so far nothing has worked. This seems to be a very simple code, and I followed instructions exactly from multiple websites. If you could give me any ideas as to why I am having this issue it would be greatly appreciated. I am using Visual Studio Express 2013.

Comment: Can you add your button code?

Comment: Did you simply copy paste the code? The event handler needs to be registered to the MenuItem and Button. Easiest way to register the click event handler is to double click on MenuItem or Button, then put the Application.Exit(); statement in the generated function.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a WPF application then use

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper method would be Application.Exit(). It terminates all message loops and closes all windows thus giving your forms the possibility to execute their cleanup code (in `Form.OnClose` etc).

`Environment.Exit` would just kill the process. If some form has e.g. unsaved changes it would not have any chances to ask the user if the person wants to save them. Also resources (database connections etc.) could not be released properly, files might not be flushed etc.

if you use multithreading, `Application.Exit()` will not terminate your threads (and thus the application will keep working in the background, even if the GUI is terminated). Therefore you must take measures to kill your threads, either in the main function (i.e. `Program.Main()`) or when in the `OnClose` event of your main form.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run has been called by checking the System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop property.  If true, then Run has been called and you can assume that a WinForms application is executing as follows.

```
If (System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop)
{
   // Use this since we are a WinForms app
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()
}
Else
{
   // Use this since we are a console app
   System.Environment.Exit(1)
}
```

Refer:http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

OR

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```